# Writing column type now has ColumnType.OPTION instead of OPTION

Tags: smartsheet-api

In the Smartsheet API, I have long had code that builds a csv file for column definitions.

Update (previous description of the problem very wrong)

All column types used to come over as

```
TEXT_NUMBER
PICKLIST
DATE
etc...
```

Now they come over as

```
ColumnType.TEXT_NUMBER
ColumnType.PICKLIST
ColumnType.DATE
etc...
```

This code

```
        for column in sheet.columns:
        (snip)
            if (get_id):
                writer.writerow( (str(column.title), str(column.type),
                              picklist, column.id) )
            else:
                writer.writerow( (str(column.title), str(column.type),
                              picklist) )
```

I hope this is new bug and can be reverted. This has only shown up today and last used was about a week or two ago at most. I have updated the package since the last time I ran this code.

Python 3.6 
Smartsheet Python SDK

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Smartsheet Python SDK did just recently change the implementation for fixed strings coming back the API to Python Enums. The `__str__` implementation for  `EnumeratedValue` was returning `class_name.name`. It has been changed to just return `name` in version 1.3.2 of the SDK. Please try the updated 1.3.2 SDK. This should address the issue.

Comment: Tim, My example is poorly written. Apologies. ALL columns are coming to the columns.csv file that I am writing.

ColumnType.TEXT_NUMBER,
ColumnType.DATE

All of them.
I'll update the original description. 

Craig

Comment: This:

print(column.type)

used to print

TEXT_NUMBER

and now prints

ColumnType.TEXT_NUMBER

I have made no changes to my code recently.

Comment: 1.3.2 broke it


  File "(snip)\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\models\sheet.py", line 92, in __setattr__
    super(Sheet, self).__setattr__(key, value)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Comment: No. Broken completely now. At least before it was giving me the data, just with the odd ColumnType.TYPE format. Now it breaks.

Comment: Craig, let's move this to Smartsheet support and see if we can't get you back up and running.

Comment: Tim, should I send an email to support and put attention you? I rolled back to 1.3.1

Comment: Yes please, they are expecting it and will loop me in when they get it.

Comment: 1.3.2 is working now. I don't know what I did wrong the first two updates, but I installed it again this morning and it generates what I expect (ie what I was getting before).